# Return Updated Column into Array Variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

This update query is part of my function

```
update  tax_table it
    set updated_by   =  1,
        updated_on   =  now(),
        customer_id  =  gs.colum,
        site_id      =  t.colum
    from    table1 ri
        inner join table2 t on t.colum = ri.colum 
        inner join table3 gs on ri.colum = gs.colum 
        inner join table4 vg on vg.colum = ri.colum     
    where   ri.table1 = _id ;
```

I want to store updated site_id into a integer array variable in my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smth like shoud do:

```
with u as (
update  tax_table it
    set updated_by   =  1,
        updated_on   =  now(),
        customer_id  =  gs.colum,
        site_id      =  t.colum
    from    table1 ri
        inner join table2 t on t.colum = ri.colum 
        inner join table3 gs on ri.colum = gs.colum 
        inner join table4 vg on vg.colum = ri.colum     
    where   ri.table1 = _id 
    returning site_id 
)
select array_agg(site_id) from u into YOUR_VAR;
```

Comment: Its Worked !! :) Thanks